# jQuery scroll (bounce) long text inside table cell

Tags: jquery

I have a table that has 2 columns, one with set width, second take the rest of page.

In first column I have another table containing 2 tr elements (this is generated by asp)

Like table shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/Misiu/y22Tk/2/

First line contains category which is short, but second lice contains subcategory with long text.

What I would like to achieve is to add a jQuery scroller that will hide my long text (like `overflow: hidden`) and after I mouse over it will scroll it.

I've managed to add this kind of scroller to div in my example, but I would like to have different effect.

I would like to see part of text visible at start (like normal `overflow: hidden`).

Right now whole text is invisible and shows only after I scroll over it.

Besides it scrolls completely off cell, that I would like is to have it wrap around that cell, so that when part of text hides on left it start showing on right or it could bounce from left to right.

Any advices appreciated :)

---

I've managed to do this: http://jsfiddle.net/Misiu/kGxm7/1/ but this is just starting point.
I need to be able to call this on multiple objects on site (on some td's in my tables)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a simple example, but it could be extended to offer more options, etc.

http://jsfiddle.net/kGxm7/2/

It is basically two jquery functions. One starts a repeating "bounce" effect, the other stops bouncing and resets the position. Call the first function on mouse over and the second on mouseout.

Comment: Awesome :D This is what I needed, just need to tweak my asp code a bit. Thanks!!!